# How to use Django AutoField to edit a modelForm?

Tags: python, django, forms

The Django doc mention that a Model AutoField will not be represented in a form built with a ModelForm.

When editing and saving that form, how should I supposed to know the underlying AutoField id value to save correctly my form data to database?

I know I can inject myself in the edit form an hidden field to know which row has been edited but is there a way Django manage that hidden field or some other mecanism automatically?

Thanks a lot

Etienne

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do that by specifying the `instance=<>` parameter when you are using `ModelForm`.
More on this in the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm)

Example usage of a create/update view:

```
def myview(request, id=None):
    if id:
        obj_to_edit = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
        form = MyForm(instance=obj_to_edit)
    else:
        obj_to_edit = None
        form = MyForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if id: #update
            form = MyForm(request.POST, instance=obj_to_edit)
        else: #create
            form = MyForm(request.POST)

    #rest of the code
```

and the URL would have something like:

```
url(r'/blah/create/', 'myview'),
url(r'/blah/edit/(?P<id>[\d+])/', 'myview')
```

Now, django understands that it needs to edit rather than create new objects.

Also note that if you are using `forms.Form`, you would have to manually query for the unique fields, or inject the hidden `id` field as you have mentioned.

Comment: I'm aware of the instance parameter, but how do you obtain your id=1 if it'S not coming in the request? This is exactly the question I have

Comment: You are initializing the instance of an object to edit. You already have access to that somehow right? My example just assumes you have it, but you can pass that as the URL parameter, and access it in the view. Just edited the answer. Hope that makes a little more sense.

Comment: Ok, but I'm curious to know if there is an easy way to make the AutoField managed the same way as the other fields (hidden or not) and not have to manage it in the url like you did?

Comment: I think you are missing something here. Without knowing which object to edit, how would you expect that instance to be updated ?

Comment: I know the object to edit but I would like to receive it in the request.POST like all the others fields and not have to manage it "differently" by passing it in the url... But to receive it in the Post the field need to be part of the form (hidden or not) but Django ModelForm are not creating the field in the form because it's an AutoField...

Comment: Then you can pass the id as a context variable, and send the id via the POST. Unless you have a very specific reason not to expose the ID, this method is not something which is recommended.

Comment: In this moment, I'm injecting manually the id field in the form on client side and it's exactly what bother me because Django should do it automatically no? I understand that when creating a new object the AutoField is not necessary but when editing it could be easier if the AutoField would be managed like all others fields to not have to inject it manually or pass it manually through the url...

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you're editing a form the specific instance that you want to edit will be identified in your URL using either the primary key or a slug field, e.g:

```
www.example.com/model/edit/6/
```

or

```
www.example.com/model/edit/object_slug/
```

You would then set up your urls.py to pass that parameter to your view, where you would use the example provided by karthkir (I'll use the primary as the example from here)

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(regex=r'^model/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'myapp.views.myview', name='add_customer'),
)
```

views.py

```
def myview(request, pk):
    obj_to_edit = MyModel.objects.get(id=pk)
    ...
```

Comment: Except in the case of formset, in which the primary key would usually be specified in the form itself.

Comment: @LieRyan: true, but the OP doesn't mention using formsets

Comment: Ok, but I'm curious to know if there is an easy way to make the AutoField managed the same way as the other fields (hidden or not) and not have to manage it in the url like you did?

Comment: The simplest way to do that would be to create a form class which adds the id as a hidden field. You could also instantiate the form as part of a formset, but that's overengineering it as far as I'm concerned